# Searching for multiple values using REST

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm attempting to search for documents that contain match a value from list of values.

The list of values are `["AGA>23/180@23221" , "AGA>24/180@23221"  ,"AGA>25/180@23221"]`

To find the documents a solution is to iterate over the each elements in the list and invoke multiple requests using a query for each element:

query 1:

```
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "mid.keyword": "AGA>23/180@20210212"
    }
  }
}
```

query 1:

```
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "mid.keyword": "AGA>24/180@20210212"
    }
  }
}
```

query 3:

```
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "mid.keyword": "AGA>25/180@20210212"
    }
  }
}
```

Can the search be combined into a single request ? When I try to combine into a single reuqest using payload:

```
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "mid.keyword": ["AGA>23/180@20210212" , "AGA>24/180@20210212" , "AGA>25/180@20210212"]
    }
  }
}
```

elastic search returns error:

```
'reason': '[term] query does not support array of values',
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`terms` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html) instead:

```
{
  "query": {
    "terms": {
      "mid.keyword": ["AGA>23/180@20210212" , "AGA>24/180@20210212" , "AGA>25/180@20210212"]
    }
  }
}
```